# How can I return multiple outputs from a Sitecore Personalize decision table?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize, decisioning

If I am returning content, offers or products from a Sitecore Personalize decision table how can I return more than 1 content/offer/product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit policy is an option on the top right-hand corner of the decision table which determines how many rules can be simultaneously satisfied. Therefore, using hit policy your decision model can be setup to return multiple outputs or have multiple rules satisfied.

For more details on hit policy see our documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-cdp-and-personalize/applying-a-hit-policy-to-a-decision-table.html

Below is an example for hit policy:
The following decision table is returning a product based on gender.

[image]

**Hit Policy: Unique**

If the Hit Policy is set to unique this decision model will fail because more than one rule is satisfied. For a Unique hit policy only one rule can be satisfied in a decision table.

[image]

**Hit Policy: First**

If the Hit Policy is set to first, the first stratified rule in the decision table will be returned.

In this case the gender of the guest I am testing with is Male, so the result returned is rule 2.

[image]

**Hit Policy: Any**

If the Hit Policy is set to any this decision model will fail because the hit policy assumes that if two rules are true, then two results will be returning the same value.

[image]

**Hit Policy: Collect List**

If the Hit Policy is set to collect, there are multiple options available on how the results will be collected together. In this example I have selected list, so all the rules that successful in the decision table will be returned in a list.

In this case the gender of the guest I am testing with is Male, so the result returned is a list of rule 2 and rule 4.

[image]

**Hit Policy: Rule Order**

If the Hit Policy is set to Rule Order, all the rules that successful in the decision table will be returned in a list in the same order as the rules are defined in the decision table.

In this case the gender of the guest I am testing with is Male, so the result returned is a list of rule 2 and rule 4.

[image]